# C for loop segmentation fault

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, for-loop, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault error when I try to compile this code on gcc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N_TIMES     600000
#define ARRAY_SIZE   10000

int main (void)
{
    double  *array = calloc(ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(double));
    double  sum = 0;
    int     i;

    double sum1 = 0;


    for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {

        int     j;

        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j += 20) {
            sum += array[j] + array[j+1] + array[j+2] + array[j+3] + array[j+4] + array[j+5] + array[j+6] + array[j+7] + array[j+8] + array[j+9];
            sum += array[j+10] + array[j+11] + array[j+12] + array[j+13] + array[j+14] + array[j+15] + array[j+16] + array[j+17] + array[j+18] + array[j+19];
            }
        }

    sum += sum1;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to speed up a for loop as much as I can so I am trying crazy things. How do I get rid of the segmentation fault? Also should I try a different method of optimization?

Comment: We need to see more code a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be better but, seeing a declaration and initialization of array would be a good start. This `array[ARRAY_SIZE]` looks pretty suspicious.

Comment: And you don't think telling us what `array` is is relevant to the question?

Comment: I changed the i's to j's. They were supposed to be j's. Now I am not getting an error. Does everything look good now?

Comment: As corrected, you're OK because ARRAY_SIZE is a multiple of 20.  If it was not, you'd be accessing memory outside the bounds of your array, or you'd need to modify the loop condition to avoid overstepping the array bounds, and some extra code to handle the remainder after you've processed all the multiples of 20 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your original problem was due to the fact that you were using `i` instead of `j` in your array index in the inner loop and since `N_TIMES` is much larger than `ARRAY_SIZE` you will end up overflowing your array bounds which is undefined behavior.

The corrected code still has one obvious problem:

```
sum += array[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

The valid indices for `array` will go from `0 to ARRAY_SIZE-1` so accessing element `ARRAY_SIZE` is invoking undefined behavior by going outside the array bounds.

Answer (score 2):

1. The compiler will almost certainly optimize better than you. Don't try to outthink the compiler.
2. Problem is almost certainly `sum += array[ARRAY_SIZE];` Array indexes in C go from 0 to size-1, so here you are probably going "one off the end"

Comment: About the first point: That's true for low-level optimization, but for everything else, DO optimize it yourself because the compiler has no idea how to do that.