# for-loop optimization using pointer

Tags: c, pointers, optimization, for-loop

I am trying to optimize code to run in under 7 seconds. I had it down to 8, and now I am trying to use pointers to speed up the code. But gcc gives an error when I try to compile:

> .c:29: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type .c:29:
>   warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast

Here is what I had before trying to use pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N_TIMES     600000
#define ARRAY_SIZE   10000

int main (void)
{
    double  *array = calloc(ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(double));
    double  sum = 0;
    int     i;

    double sum1 = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {

        int     j;

        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j += 20) {
            sum += array[j] + array[j+1] + array[j+2] + array[j+3] + array[j+4] + array[j+5] + array[j+6] + array[j+7] + array[j+8] + array[j+9];
            sum1 += array[j+10] + array[j+11] + array[j+12] + array[j+13] + array[j+14] + array[j+15] + array[j+16] + array[j+17] + array[j+18] + array[j+19];
            }

        }

    sum += sum1;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I have when I use pointers (this code generates the error):

```
int     *j;

        for (j = array; j < &array[ARRAY_SIZE]; j += 20) {
            sum += *j + *(j+1) + *(j+2) + *(j+3) + *(j+4) + *(j+5) + *(j+6) + *(j+7) + *(j+8) + *(j+9);
            sum1 += *(j+10) + *(j+11) + *(j+12) + *(j+13) + *(j+14) + *(j+15) + *(j+16) + *(j+17) + *(j+18) + *(j+19);
            }
```

How do I fix this error? Btw I don't want suggestions on alternative ways to try to optimize the code. This is a homework problem that has constraints about what I'm allowed to do. I think once I get this pointer thing fixed it will run under 7 seconds and i'll be good to go.

Comment: I highly doubt pointers are going to speed up this code.

Comment: See also related (but not identical) questions from the same OP: [Is this a proper `for` loop optimization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325609/is-this-a-proper-for-loop-optimization) and [C `for` loop segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325131/c-for-loop-segmentation-fault).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast

This means that you tried to compare a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type, and did so without a cast.

```
double  *array = calloc(ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(double));
int     *j;
```

Pointers to `double` and pointers to `int` are not directly comparable. You aren't allowed to compare `j` to `array` for this reason. Perhaps you meant to declare `j` as a pointer to `double` ?

Comment: But aren't I comparing an int pointer to an address which is also an int?

Comment: @chillpenguin: Pointers are *usually implemented* as addresses. Pointers are not, conceptually, addresses. Consider a pointer to int "x" -- the expression `++x` must increment the "address value" x by `sizeof(int)`, not 1 (assuming address are being used to implement pointers).

Comment: if i made j a double pointer would that work right? Or do I have to cast things?

Comment: @chillpenguin: The most common machines which may not implement pointers as memory addresses are those machines which use segmentation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation

Comment: @chillpenguin: If you intend to read `double`s from `j`, then `j` does indeed need to be a pointer to `double`. As implemented now, assuming `int` is 32 bits and `double` is 64 bits (typical), you're not adding `double`s. :)

Comment: All I did was change j to a double * and now it works. It runs in 5.8 seconds too which means the pointer version does indeed go faster.

Comment: @BillyONeal the value of +1 in ++x depends on the context of x.  +1 means plus one element of the array pointed to by x.

Comment: @Jack: No, because `x` need not point to an element of an array. e.g. `calloc` does not return arrays.

Comment: @Jack: Erm, why not? `int* x = calloc(42, sizeof(int)); ++x;` is completely valid.

Comment: @BillyONeal, you jest, you know the semicolons make then separate stmts.

Comment: @Jack: I don't see how that is relevant. In those two statements, there is no array. There is a pointer `x`, and that pointer is pointing to a memory block with allocated storage duration. `x` does **not** point to an array, nor does it point to an element of any array.

Comment: @BillyONeal, x points to type ints, when incremented the x pointer will be increased by the number of bytes used to represent ints on the target machine for the compiler.  i.e. +1 in the context of ints, compared to +1 in the context of floats or whatever.

Comment: @BillyONeal, also C believes that you say what you mean.  If you have allocated storage and pointed to it by an int ptr, then that storage is an array of ints.  What else could it be?  And if it something else then define x as that something else and not as an int ptr.

Answer (score 0):

C is a statically typed language, and comparisons across pointer types will give you errors.  There is some implicit casting in certain cases, like if you compare a double to an int, because comparing numbers is a common operation.  Comparing pointers of different types isn't.

Further, when you increment a pointer over an array, it uses the size of it's dereferenced element to know how far in memory to move.  Moving with an int over an array of doubles will lead to issues.

A double will move farther then an int, so you will get more interations with an int pointer anyway.

You could explicitly cast things, but really you should be using a double * for an array of doubles.

Comment: There is no such thing as "implicit casting." A cast is a request to the compiler to either ignore something in the type system, or to generate code to perform a conversion. Perhaps you meant to refer to the "usual arithmetic *conversions*" (C11 6.3.1.8)?

Comment: You are correct.  My teacher and book called these implicit casts, but that is not how they are described in the C standard. Would you mind if I edited my comment to more accurately reflect this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be greatly surprised if moving from an array representation to a pointer representation would yield much (if any) speedup, as both are memory addresses (and memory offsets) in the final outputted code.  Remember, the array representation is actually a pointer representation in different clothing too.

Instead, I'd look towards one of two techniques:

1. Embedded MMX representations, to do multiple addition operations within the same register, under the same clock cycle.  Then, you need one operation near the end to combine the high double with the low double.
2. Scatter / Gather algorithims to spread the addition operation across multiple cores (nearly every CPU these days has 4 cores available, if not 16 pseudo-cores (a la hyper-threading))

Beyond that, you can do a few attempts at cache analysis, and at storing intermediates in different registers.  There seems to be a deep chain of additions in each of your computations.  Breaking them up might yield the ability to spread the on-cpu storage across more registers.

Most operations become memory bound.  20 is a really strange boundary for loop unrolling.  Doubles probably are 16 bits, so 20 doubles is 320 bits, which is probably not aligned to your memory cache line size.  Try making sure that multiples of your unrolled loop align cleanly with your architecture's level 1 cache, and you might avoid a page fault as you read across cache boundaries.  Doing so will speed up your program by some (but who knows how much).

Comment: In C, `int[]` and `int*` are distinct types. Arrays are not pointers, even if they decay into pointers when passed to functions. Most importantly for this code, an optimizer can make assumptions about an array which it cannot make about pointers.

Comment: I agree, the compiler might have a better time with the array, due to the extra hints the array allows in the C type system.  The C type system doesn't survive the translation to assembly / machine code (too bad).  From my assembly days, it would be quite a shock to discover that array offsets are implemented in any other form than `address + offset`, which is what the pointer math does, but without the extra guarantees that arrays make.

Comment: I fixed the error and it now compiles just fine. It DOES run faster using pointers btw. It is down to 5.8 seconds from 8 seconds.

Comment: Well, the proof is in the testing (when it comes to optimization).  Thank you for the update, and I'll take my lumps as being completely wrong in my assumptions.  Profiling is funny that way.  Glad to hear of your success.

Comment: I learned about using pointers to step through an array in class but I don't remember why it is faster... I just remember my instructor said you will need to use it on this assignment to break 7 seconds. Like you said though, the proof is in the testing!

Answer (score 0):

" When you increment a pointer over an array, it uses the size of it's dereferenced element to know how far in memory to move. Moving with an int over an array of doubles will lead to issues ".

To avoid your warn: do the below one

```
for (j= (int *)array; j < (int *)&array[ARRAY_SIZE]; j += 20)
```

Comment: Instead I just made j a double. That works just as well right?

Comment: @chillpenguin, correct, because both variables have the same data type, thus no conversion is necessary.  Good call!